# TypeError: Object #<Socket> has no method 'destory'

Tags: node.js, sockets, destroy

I'm having trouble handling a ECONNREFUSED error from my net.createConnection in node.js.

When I connect I get ECONREFUSED (which is fine), and I handle it this way:

```
testSocket.addListener('error', function(message) {
    testSocket.destory();
});
```

That then gives me the error: TypeError: Object # has no method 'destory'.

My goal is to close the socket based on the error, which will then start a reconnect process.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean `destroy`?  You spelt it incorrectly (`distORy`)

Comment: Wow, I stared at this way to long! Thanks for the catch!

Comment: Happens to us all ;)